# Where to store user ids of users with a cookie and no session (Remember me)

Tags: php, session

I have read a ton of question about it and the discussions are different along with the answers on this matter.

I need to have the User ID in order to retrieve his data from the DB and create a session with this data in order to create a continues login.

Hashing the session:

```
function createNewUserSession($uid, $email, $salt){
    $session_key = $email.$salt;
    $options = [
        'cost' => 11
    ];
    $session_key = password_hash($session_key, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
    $connect = mysqliConnect();

    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET";
    $query .= " session_key = '$session_key'";
    $query .= " WHERE id = '$uid'";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    return $session_key;
}

function generateRandomString($length) {
        return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()_+|"}?><~', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
}

    $user_session_salt = generateRandomString(32);

    if (isset($_COOKIE['sk'])) {
        if (password_verify($email.$_COOKIE['sk'], $session_key)) {
        // Creating Sessions
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
        $_SESSION['fName'] = $fName;
        $_SESSION['lName'] = $lName;
        } else {
            // Creating New Sessions
            createNewUserSession($uid, $email, $user_session_salt);
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
            $_SESSION['fName'] = $fName;
            $_SESSION['lName'] = $lName;

            // Creating Cookies
            setcookie("sk", $user_session_salt, time() + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/', '.mywebsite.io');
        }
    }
```

Renew Session:

```
function restoreSession($uid) {
    $connect = mysqliConnect();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = '$uid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $uid = $row['id'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $fName = $row['first_name'];
        $lName = $row['last_name'];
        $session_key = $row['session_key'];

        if (isset($_COOKIE['sk']) && !isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {

            $user_salt = $_COOKIE['sk'];

            if (password_verify($email.$user_salt, $session_key)) {
                // Creating Sessions
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
                $_SESSION['fName'] = $fName;
                $_SESSION['lName'] = $lName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is not perfect, but I'm still learning and need some adequate input on this matter.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: Perfect, I was going to get over the procedural style anyway and you just pushed me to consider it again. I'm a bit short of time on this small project though, and I believe it will take quite some time to refactor the code. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: The good thing is you can migrate to it incrementally, they're inter-compatible. That being said, you're creating a massive amount of technical debt with this code and I'd strongly encourage you to stop and consider your options if this is going to be a long-term concern for you and not just a quick experimental app.

Comment: Accepted, thanks again :)